# Why do i see errors in my console but the emulator still runs my project?

Tags: android, emulation

I'm trying to understand how a launcher works, so i'm checking out the sample code "Home" which is included in adroid sdk. When i run the project, below is what i see in console. Since the emulator seems to work perfectly, i wonder why i see the "No Launcher activity found!" error in console?

```
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] ------------------------------
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] Android Launch!
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] **No Launcher activity found!**
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] **The launch will only sync the application package on the** device!
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] Performing sync
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVDNew' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)
[2012-01-30 11:24:18 - Home] Uploading Home.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-30 11:24:19 - Home] Installing Home.apk...
[2012-01-30 11:24:29 - Home] Success!
[2012-01-30 11:24:29 - Home] \Home\bin\Home.apk installed on device
[2012-01-30 11:24:29 - Home] Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

set the following intent filters to your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I tried it removes the error but it doesn't actually change anything else, at least this is what i see. Moreover, i'm thinking why a sample in android sdk would forget to add these lines. and As i searched there is not such a line in a launcher. This shouldn't be about coding but something else.